# How to Handle Non-Existing Records in CASE WHEN SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, null, sql-update, case

I am trying to update a value of column based on a `SELECT` that returns value from its `CASE/WHEN/ELSE` statement, e.g.

```
UPDATE TBL T
SET T.COL1 = (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN H.COLH = 'XY' THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
    END
  FROM HTBL H
  WHERE T.ID = H.ID
    AND /* Other conditions */
)
WHERE T.RN = 100
  AND /* Other conditions */
```

The problem is, if the record doesn't exist in `HTBL` table, then no value is assigned to `T.COL`, and therefore `T.COL` remains `NULL`. In such scenario, I would like to set `T.COL` to 'N' just when the actual value of `H.COLH` is 'N'.

Adding `WHEN H.COLH IS NULL` doesn't work. I tried to wrap the entire `SELECT` in another `SELECT... FROM DUAL` with another `CASE/WHEN/ELSE`, but it returns multiple values.

Is there a way to treat `NULL` values as 'N' even though there is no record in `TBLH` (let alone `TBLH.COLH`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
UPDATE TBL T
    SET T.COL1 = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM HTBL H
                                    WHERE T.ID = H.ID AND
                                          /* Other conditions */ AND
                                          H.COLH = 'XY'
                                   )
                       THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
                  END)
WHERE T.RN = 100 AND
      /* Other conditions */
```

I think `EXISTS` better captures the logic that you want as well.

Comment: It does capture the logic perfectly. Wasn't aware that one can use `CASE` like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the subquery in a `COALESCE`:

```
UPDATE TBL T
SET T.COL1 = COALESCE( (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN H.COLH = 'XY' THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
    END
  FROM HTBL H
  WHERE T.ID = H.ID
    AND /* Other conditions */
), 'N')
WHERE T.RN = 100
  AND /* Other conditions */
```